# Helm Umbrella render files to subchart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

My *parent* `Chart.yaml` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: solution-chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: 1.16.0
dependencies:
- name: service1
  version: 0.1.0
- name: service2
  version: 0.1.0
- name: service3
  version: 0.1.0
```

All of the services above expect to receive certificate files. I was wondering if there is an option to render these files to them from the parent chart, let's say:

`values.yaml:`

```
global:
  certificates:
    firstPath: {{ .Files.Get "certs/key.pem" }}
    secondPath: {{ .Files.Get "certs/certs.pem" }}
```

But it's not possible since `values.yaml` cannot be templated. Also, I cannot pass the path of the files to the subchart since it won't recognize these files as they're not in the same context.

Comment: I've had good luck using [Helmfile](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/) for this: it _can_ use Go tempating in per-chart values files (though its file setup is slightly different from plain Helm's), and it avoids a couple of technical problems around umbrella charts (combining dependencies, conflicts between helper functions).